# In Euchre, Can a person of the opposing team go alone if trump was ordered up by the other team?

Tags: house-rules, euchre

I ordered up trump from the dealer of the opposing team and the same person said they were going alone and asked for their partners best card. Is that legal in the euchre rules?

Answer (score 3):

According to both the [Bicycle Card Company Rules](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/euchre/) and the [EuchreLinks.Com website Rulee](http://www.euchrelinks.com/rules.html) only the person actually *naming* the trump denomination, termed the *maker*, has the option of going alone.

> #### Playing Alone
>
> If the player who fixes the trump suit believes it will be to his side's advantage to play without the help of his partner's cards, the player exercises this option by declaring "alone" distinctly at the time of making the trump. This player's partner then turns his cards face down and does not participate in the play.

Or

> The player, who chooses the trump suit, either by accepting the up-card's suit as trump, or by naming a different suit, is called the maker. Before the play of the hand begins, the maker may announce; "Alone", in which case the maker's partner places his hand facedown and does not participate in the play.

Note that both these Rule compilations do not include your House Rule of a card being passed from *maker's partner* to the *maker*.

Comment: So, it's not in the rules about ordering up the dealer and the same dealer/person says they're going alone afterwards correct?

Comment: And also asking for their partner's best card

Comment: This was very upsetting to me as I've never seen a play like that and I've been playing for many years and I need clarification regarding that. Thanks!

Comment: @ConnieArnoldPotter: The presence of the word "same" in your first comment makes it completely uninterpretable. Yes, my post completely refutes your claim in comment #2 - though of course a group of players is allowed to adopt any House Rules that they mutually agree on. The phrase "*a play like that*" in your 3rd comment has no obvious antecedent - either in your post, my post, or your comments #1 and #2  - and thus again is completely uninterpretable.

Comment: The dealer was to the right of me and I ordered up trump and she( same person) in turn right after that said she was going alone and wanted her partners best. I didn't think that could happen after I ordered her up. Please let me know about the rules in that situation. Also, my partner and I got 3 tricks so how would the scoring go there? Do we get 1 point or 2 points for euchering the dealer that went alone?

Comment: @ConnieArnoldPotter: Comments are ephemeral - subject at any time and without notice to deletion by moderators. Please put: (1) question clarifications in the body of the question post itself; and (2) New questions in their own, new, question post.

Comment: Can someone please answer my question above? I appreciate it very much!

Comment: @ConnieArnoldPotter: What part of this statement in my post above, "*only the person actually naming the trump denomination, termed the maker, has the option of going alone*", is not an answer to your question? Also, the answer to [your second question (here)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45986/euchre-card-game) seems to address the scoring aspect.

Comment: Okay and Yes,that's a good answer and I didn't think that a person could go alone if trump was already ordered up by the opposing team. Thank you for your help! Connie Potter

Comment: @ConnieArnoldPotter: The usual way to express gratitude is to click the little up-arrow beside all answers of assistance, and the checkmark beside the best answer. Doing the latter also gives you 2 additional rep on the site.

Answer (score -2):

First it depends what euchre you are playing such as railroad, bid euchre or sometimes by house rules. In regular euchre you don't ask for your partners best but you can go alone against if those are the house rules. A similar situation is if the opponent reneges on a lone hand the maker gets his lone hand( not the usual 2 ) otherwise people would just renege, but also if the maker reneges on his lone hand the other team gets 4 points. It states quite clearly who ever reneges the opposing team gets the 4 points this makes sense to me because the rules do not say if the dealers reneges so I would assume it means who ever renges on loan hand the other team gets the point.)  Now on a go alone against its the team that gets at least 3 tricks that gets the 4 points, Remember these are house rules or different games of euchre not regular euchre but some may adopt these rules as house rules.

Answer (score -2):

There are many variations to the rules of Euchre. In most tournaments I have played we play Stick the Dealer" Euchre. That is where, after 7 Passes, the Dealer MUST Name Trump. Also, there is no passing of cards from one player to their partner or anyone else for any reason. Also, no one can OVERBID or change the bid or change who will play the hand once a bid is announced. The best you an do is Euchre someone if you have a better hand play it better than they do. If a Bid is announced in error, that player must play the hand in that Suit. If a card is played in error, that card is in play and can not be taken back off the table unless it is an accidental renege.  Then it can be set aside but left on the table until it is the correct time to play it and it must be played when that time comes, no matter how ill advised that play is. If someone reneges and does not correct his error, then that team is penalized.  If the error was made by the Makers, then 2 points is awarded to the Defenders. If the error is made by the Defenders, then 2 points (4 points during a Loner) is awarded. Stealing The Deal is NOT a rule in Tournament Games but some play that way in general play. I personally do not do that but I do play with some people who do. I tolerate them because I like to play and winning is simply one of the many benefits I derive from the game. I must admit, I have Stolen the Deal more than once myself. No one likes to make mistakes but it happens. Being kind and understanding while obeying the rules is always a good idea.  Everyone makes mistakes eventually and being kind is good karma in my book.