# Euchre Card Game

Tags: house-rules, euchre

I need clarification on an issue that I had with playing euchre.

As I ordered up, the dealer (on my right), and right after that, she said that she was going alone and asked for her partner's best card. (Disputed validity as in [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45961/in-euchre-can-a-person-of-the-opposing-team-go-alone-if-trump-was-ordered-up-by), but accepted at the time.)

Ny partner and I got 3 tricks, so would we get just 1 point or 2 points for euchreing her? I'm very confused here and need someone to help. I appreciate it very much! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Euchre, Can a person of the opposing team go alone if trump was ordered up by the other team?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45961/in-euchre-can-a-person-of-the-opposing-team-go-alone-if-trump-was-ordered-up-by)

Comment: This should be answered by your other question which states you can't go alone unless you are the maker so this would be a house rule to decide on.

Comment: I have reduced this question down to just the scoring aspect of the disputed occurrence. There should be no reason remaining to close it, with the duplicated portion removed and replaced by a reference to the earlier question.

Answer (score 2):

Your side named the trump suit by ordering up; and then scored the requisite three tricks for making contract.

Your side scores just a single point.

As noted in the referenced question:

- Your opponent, the Dealer, had no basis for the claim of going alone.
- Your opponent's claim of *best card* from partner's hand is doubly unsupported:

  - It is not part of the standard rules when going alone; and
  - If a trump, it penalizes your side for *forcing up*, by providing her with **two** trumps on top of her originally dealt holding.